# Use result of IF formula in single cell Excel array formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column `J` with the below array formula:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER($H$5:$H$263), $H$5:$H$263, $I$5:$I$263)
```

And a cell on a summary line that references the contents of that column:

```
=SUMIF($J$5:$J$267,"<"&(TODAY()+365), $L$5:$L$263)
```

The above gives me the result I want, but I am wanting to consolidate this down into a single formula.

I have tried the below:

```
=SUMIF(IF(ISNUMBER($H$5:$H$263), $H$5:$H$263, $I$5:$I$263),"<"&(TODAY()+365), $L$5:$L$263)
```

But it ends up only summing the contents of the left side of the `IF`

So the below can get me what I want:

```
=SUMIF(IF(ISNUMBER($H$5:$H$263), $I$5:$I$263, $H$5:$H$263),"<"&(TODAY()+365), $L$5:$L$263) + SUMIF(IF(ISNUMBER($H$5:$H$263), $H$5:$H$263, $I$5:$I$263),"<"&(TODAY()+365), $L$5:$L$263)
```

But I'm not sure what I am doing wrong with the first shorter formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this array formula:

```
=SUM(IF(IF(ISNUMBER($H$5:$H$263),$H$5:$H$263,$I$5:$I$263)<TODAY()+365,$L$5:$L$263))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

You can use SUMPRODUCT without the need for CSE:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((ISNUMBER($H$5:$H$263)*($H$5:$H$263)+(NOT(ISNUMBER($H$5:$H$263)) * ($I$5:$I$263)))<TODAY()+365)*$L$5:$L$263)
```

I would also recommend the use of `EDATE(TODAY(),12)` in place of `TODAY()+365` to deal with leap year.